# How to resize Image in ImageView without affecting the TableRow android

Tags: android

I am trying change image size in TableRow, always when i use padding or margin
the edited column row always changes size compared to the others rows. I'm without ideas
trying LinearLayout and ConstraintLayout and always column row change size.

[image: result]

My code:

```
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@drawable/keyboard_divider"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end">

        <TableRow
            style="@style/keyboard_row"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <TableRow...>

        <TableRow...>

        <TableRow
            style="@style/keyboard_row">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_bv"
                style="@style/keyboard_button"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_margin="144dp"
                    android:id="@+id/t9_key_clear"
                    style="@style/keyboard_button"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_0"
                style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
                android:text="@string/number_zero"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/t9_key_backspace"
                style="@style/keyboard_button"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_backspace"/>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: You should put all those three buttons in a same `LinearLayout`, use `android:layout_weight="1.0"` for each of them. Do the same for each row as well.

Comment: Thanks, this working when I replace TableRow with LinearLayout.